# python range and for loop understanding

Tags: python

I am new to python / coding and looking to understanding the range function more and how it is used in conjunction with the "for" loop.

So I know that the range function takes in 3 parameters: range(start, stop, step). For the below function, I passed in my array called test_numbers, then created a "for" loop where "i" starts counting from len(list_of_numbers)-1 (to give me the index values)

I was expecting the result for "i" to print 0,1,2,3,4,5 but it only printed 5 for "i". I am wondering why is that? If I put 6 as the "stop" argument, would it not just print from range start of the length of the array as in [0,1,2,3,4,5] all the way then stop before 6? that is my confusion. Any help /explanation would be great!

```
test_numbers = [1,2,4,5,6]

def testRange(list_of_numbers):
    for i in range(len(list_of_numbers), 6):
        print(i)

testRange(test_numbers)
```

The result: `5`

Was expecting: `0,1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words: What do you expect will be the result of `len(list_of_numbers)`? What does `range` mean? What do the values that you pass to it indicate? In particular, if you call `range` with two numbers, what do those numbers mean?

Comment: "So I know that the range function takes in 3 parameters: range(start, stop, step)." What values do you want the `range` to contain? Therefore, what should the `start` be equal to? What should the `stop` be equal to?

Comment: As an aside: in real, well written code, `range` is **rarely** used for `for` loops. Almost every example of it that you will find out there is **bad code** that you should not try to emulate. It is written by people who either do not properly understand Python's `for` loop, or who have internalized habits from other programming languages that are inappropriate in Python. (No offense to the inevitable swarm of people who have the rare good reason to do this and will see this comment.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `range()` is very frequently used in `for` loops for good reasons. The only case where it's inappropriate is if you're looping over a sequence, in which case you should just use `for item in sequence:` rather than `for index in range(len(sequence)):`

Comment: @Barmar eh, I suppose the common use is for iterating a set number of times. I rather would prefer dedicated syntax for that, but the language is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `range()` with two arguments, the first argument is the starting number, and the second argument is the end (non-inclusive). So you're starting from `len(list_of_numbers)`, which is `5`, and you're ending at `6`. So it just prints `5`.

To get the results you want, the starting number should be `0`, and the end should be `len(list_of_numbers)+1`. If you call it with one argument, that's the end, and `0` is the default start. So use

```
for i in range(len(list_of_numbers)+1):
```

or if you want to pass the start explicitly:

```
for i in range(0, len(list_of_numbers)+1):
```

Comment: The apparently desired result probably isn't very *useful*, though. I have learned to treat questions like OP's with great suspicion, because there is typically an underlying (misguided) desire to use the values from the `range` as indices into the original list. If that's the case here, then the result wouldn't even be correct for that purpose.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel They're just trying to understand the principles. Of course the result isn't useful, it's just example code.

Comment: got it! Thank you, Barmar. so basically what i did was declared a "start" value explicitly. But if I pass in only 1 argument into range, then that will be used as the "stop" and the "start" would be the default of 0. 

The documentation did not mention that if i declare one argument then that will be used as a stop, rather than start. interesting! I was viewing the range(start, stop, step) in that order where if I pass in one parameter, ti'll be the start.. makes sense now.

Comment: The documentation does explain that. See the two syntax lines at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range. It shows `range(stop)` and `range(start, stop, [,step])`

Comment: But you were passing multiple arguments, and you still expected it to start at 0 rather than the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

`range` gives you and iterator between `(start, end)` `end` not included.
So in your case the iterator is `(start=len(list_of_numbers), end=6)`.
Since `len(list_of_numbers) = 5`, this translates to `range(5,6)` which is 1 element, 5, since 6 is excluded.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Answer (score 0):

`range` stop parameter is exclusive and start is inclusive - if you provided `len` result (of 5) and 6 as the stop then the `range` result will contain only one element `[5]`

If you'd like to have `0..6` you should use

```
range(0, 6)
```

or, what you probably want to do to iterate over all array indices

```
range(0, len (list_of_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just iterate throught list, beacause it is iterable:

```
test_numbers = [1,2,4,5,6]
def testRange(list_of_numbers):
    for i in list_of_numbers:
        print(i)

testRange(test_numbers)
```